# Switching to relative location

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

Hi Wonder if anyone can point me in the right direction.

I'm after some code that I can put on a link that will go to the current page url but in a separate folder or add a language identifier into the url.

So for example, if someone is on FAQ.aspx , they click the Italian link in the menu and it will send them to it-FAQ.aspx or /it/FAQ.aspx and the same for other pages.

Does that make sense? and is it possible, and can someone point me into the direction of where to look

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its possible, you need to get first actual url from browser and put the countrycode at begining.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

Get first pathname of the current url, then put language code in front and change href of the link with jquery :

```
<html>
 <a class="switch_language" data-country-code="it" href="">Italian</a>
 <a class="switch_language" data-country-code="de" href="">German</a>
```

and...

```
<script>
$('.switch_language').each(function() {
 $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('data-country-code') + '/' + location.pathname);
});
```

Your urls of the language links will be look like this

```
/it/faq.aspx
/de/faq.aspx
```

Comment: Is it possible to amend this as currently it puts all the subfolders in the new url; 
so for example the page is at:
domain.com/subsite1/subsite2/pages/faq.aspx using the script above it goes to 

domain.com/subsite1/subsite2/pages/de//subsite1/subsite2/pages/faq.aspx

so it adds all those subsites in again, the url path I would want it to take would be:

domain.com/subsite1/subsite2/de/pages/faq.aspx  does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Using a `data` attribute, you can store the "part to add to the URL" on the link. You can read it using the [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

Then... If you split the actual URL by the `/`, you can reassemble it and insert the part to be added.

This script will works on any page.

```js
$(".menu .lang").on("click",function(){
  
  // Get the actual page URL
  var thisPage = location.href;
  console.log(thisPage);
  
  // Split the URL by the "/"
  var splitted = thisPage.split("/");
  var splittedLength = splitted.length;
  
  // Get the data-lang value
  var insert = $(this).data("lang");
  
  // Re-assemble the URL except the last part
  var destination="";
  for (i=0;i<splittedLength-1;i++){
    destination += splitted[i]+"/";
  }
  
  // Add the part to "insert" and last part of the URL
  destination += insert+"/"+splitted[splittedLength-1];
  
  // OR
  // destination += insert+"-"+splitted[splittedLength-1];  // See explanation below the snippet.
   
  // Go to that page!
  console.log(destination);
  //location.assign(destination);  // Commented for this demo...
  
});
```

```css
.menu a{
  display:block;
  text-decoration:underline;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>FAQ</h1>
<div class="menu">
  <a class="lang" data-lang="it">Italiano</a>
  <a class="lang" data-lang="en">english</a>
  <a class="lang" data-lang-"fr">Français</a>
</div>
```

Here, the language parameter is added in between `/` like a it's a directory... But you can easilly add it to the page name like it-FAQ.aspx.